# I want to use YOLOv2 for person detection in real time on Raspberry Pi. But it is too slow on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, computer-vision

I want to use YOLO for person detection in real time on Raspberry Pi. But it is too slow on Raspberry Pi. Can anyone give me suggestion to improve it? One thing I can think of is to train YOLO for Person class only instead of all classes. But will this improve the detection speed ? Please help.

Comment: Are you using already trained model on RPI?

Comment: When I run YOLOv2 on RPI, it kills my process. And on laptop it is very slow.